# NodeJS: How can i return MySQL query's response in promise loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, for-loop, promise

I have an array of events. With the help of promise and loop, i'am trying to get members for each event. But it is returning query in response. Here is my Code:

```
var promiseArray = [];
rows.forEach(function (element) {
    element.members = db.query("MySQL query");
    promiseArray.push(element);
});

return Promise.all(promiseArray).then((data) => {
    response.send({data: data});
});
```

Here is the output:

```
{"data":[{"id":346,"owner_id":1,"title":"test","description":"","location":"","location_latitude":"","location_longitude":"","event_date":"546456453","created_at":"1522674310271","members":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"_callSite":{},"_ended":false,"_idleNext":null,"_idlePrev":null,"_idleStart":null,"_idleTimeout":-1,"_repeat":null,"sql":"SELECT event_members.*, users.name, users.country_code, users.phone_number, users.profile_picture FROM event_members LEFT JOIN users ON event_members.user_id = users.id where event_members.event_id=346","typeCast":true,"nestTables":false,"_resultSet":null,"_results":[],"_fields":[],"_index":0,"_loadError":null}}]}
```

And if i execute the query like:

```
var getEventMembersPromise = eventMembersModel.getEventMemberByEventId(element.id);
getEventMembersPromise.then(function (event_members) {
    element.members = event_members;
    promiseArray.push(element);
}, function (err) {
    response.status(422).send({msg: commonFunctions.getErrorMessage(2)});
    return true;
}).catch((err) => {
    response.status(422).send({msg: commonFunctions.getErrorMessage(2)});
    return true;
});
```

it returns empty array.

Comment: I'd have to guess that `db.query("MySQL query")` returns `members`. not Promise and that `Promise .all()` is unnecessary.